# nVidia GeForce4 MX 440 with AGP8X in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10

How I can install the driver for nVidia GeForce4 MX 440 with AGP8X in Ubuntu 13.10?

or isn't supported by this Ubuntu version?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it is supported very well by the Nouveau driver, I get glitches all over my screen... I have already installed the "Nvidia 173 driver" but it only gets worse --1024x768 tops.

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded with an MX 420 by using the Nouveau driver but disabling acceleration.  See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/395431) for the details.

Answer (score 0):

I also had glitches with my Nvidia NV18 [GeForce4 MX 440 AGP 8x] under Lubuntu 14.04 (with the Nouveau driver). I tried to use without any success several versions of the Nvidia proprietary drivers. No more glitches with these drivers but impossible to get the 1920x1080 correct display resolution I had with the Nouveau Driver. Finally I found a solution with the Nouveau Driver: glitches disappeared when changing the "sub-pixel geometry" parameter value from RGB to None. As my Lubuntu version is set to French, this can be done through Menu/Preferences/Personnaliser l'apparence/ and select the Tab "Police" in the new windows or alternatively you can open a Xterm console and enter the "lxappearance" command and select the tab "Police".

Hope this can help.